# How to write a function with mapping of all objects inside?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am stuck with one task and I don't understand how to solve it..

I have a map with lists inside:

```dart
final Map states = {
  "Anxiety": [], 
  "Stress": [], 
  "Involvement": [], 
  "Relaxation": [], 
  "Fatigue": [],
};
```

And I get data from my API, that returns a list with maps:

```dart
final data = [
  {
    id: 1, 
    states: {
      Anxiety: 2, 
      Stress: 1, 
      Chronic Fatigue: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2, 
    states: {
      Stress: 1, 
      Fatigue: 1, 
      Involvement: 1, 
      Slight Fatigue: 2, 
      Anxiety: 5, 
      Relaxation: 2, 
      Chronic Fatigue: 3,
    },
  },
];
```

Maximum elements of states is 7.

API can even returns `states: null`. There is no persistent data, api can return 2 values(`states: {"Anxiety":2, "Stress": 1}`), three, etc.

And I want to write a function summarize all integers of elements in states, let's take `id:2`. I summarize values => **Stress(1) + Fatigue(1) + Involvement(1) + Slight Fatigue(2) + Anxiety(5) + Relaxation(2) + Chronic Fatigue(3) == 15**

And then I find percentage of each element: **Stress: (1 / 15) * 100 == 6.6%, Involvement: (1 / 15) * 100 == 6.6%, Fatigue(Here I Summarize Fatigue, Slight Fatigue,Chronic Fatigue):6 / 15 == 40%, Anxiety: (5 / 15) * 100 == 33.3%, Relaxation: (2 / 15) * 100 == 13.3%**

And then I push to Map the values, like this, let's take `{"Anxiety": []}` for example:

if (Anxiety == 1) then we push to Anxiety array **1**, if  anxiety >= 25% then we push **2**, if anxiety >= 50% then we push **3** else we push **0**

And the result of **id=2** should be like this:

```dart
final Map states = {
  "Anxiety": [1], 
  "Stress": [1], 
  "Involvement": [1], 
  "Relaxation": [1], 
  "Fatigue": [2],
};
```

And the final result should be like this**(id:1, id:2)**:

```dart
final Map states = {
  "Anxiety": [3,1], 
  "Stress": [2,1], 
  "Involvement": [0,1], 
  "Relaxation": [0,1], 
  "Fatigue": [2,2],
};
```

How to write this function, I tried to map all that stuff but it was getting too complicated and I couldn't achieve any results...

Comment: Question is too broad.
Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem.  its better to separate your quesstion into 2-4 question

Comment: @newbiras take a look at updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I submit my answer I would like to say I agree with pmatatias.

I am assuming your dataset looks like this:

```dart
// This is not needed
// final Map states = {
//  "Anxiety": [],
//  "Stress": [],
//  "Involvement": [],
//  "Relaxation": [],
//  "Fatigue": []
//};

final data = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "states": {"Anxiety": 2, "Stress": 1, "Chronic Fatigue": 1}
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "states": {
      "Stress": 1,
      "Fatigue": 1,
      "Involvement": 1,
      "Slight Fatigue": 2,
      "Anxiety": 5,
      "Relaxation": 2,
      "Chronic Fatigue": 3
    }
  }
];
```

If it's not then you have to use `json.decode`.

Then extract data from above dataset:

```dart
_function(List data) {
  Map<String, dynamic> _result = {};

  for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    _result[data[i]['id'].toString()] = _addUpAndGetPercentage(
       data[i]['states'] != null ? data[i]['states'].keys.toList(): [], data[i]['states'] != null ? data[i]['states'].values.toList(): []);
  }

  return _result;
}

//Function to get percentage
_addUpAndGetPercentage(List<String> keys, List<int> data) {
  int total = 0;
  Map<String, double> _result = {};

  for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    total += data[i];
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    _result[keys[i]] =
        (data[i] / total) * 100; // Multiplying by 100 not necessary you can use (data[i] / total)
  }

  return _result;
}
```

Then create a function to sort percentage. For example I chose:

**if anxiety >= 10% then we push 1, if anxiety >= 25% then we push 2, if anxiety >= 50% then we push 3 else we push 0**

```dart
// You can change to your own parameters here
int sortPercentage(double percentage) {
  if (percentage >= 10 && percentage < 25) {
    return 1;
  } else if (percentage >= 25 && percentage < 50) {
    return 2;
  } else if (percentage >= 50) {
    return 3;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

//OR

//If you use (data[i] / total)

int sortPercentage(double percentage) {
  if (percentage >= 0.1 && percentage < 0.25) {
    return 1;
  } else if (percentage >= 0.25 && percentage < 0.50) {
    return 2;
  } else if (percentage >= 0.50) {
    return 3;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Finally extract the data and  sort:

```dart
getFinalResult(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
  Map<String, dynamic> _result = {};
  int _length = data.entries.toList().length;

  for (int x = 0; x < _length; x++) {
    var x_data = data.entries.toList()[x];
    var x_data_length = x_data.value.entries.toList().length;

    for (int y = 0; y < x_data_length; y++) {
      var y_data = data.entries.toList()[x].value.entries.toList()[y];
      if (_result.containsKey(y_data.key)) {
        _result.update(y_data.key, (value) {
          List _list = [];
          _list.addAll(value);
          _list.add(sortPercentage(y_data.value));

          return _list;
        });
      } else {
        _result[y_data.key] = [sortPercentage(y_data.value)];
      }
    }
  }

  return _result;
}
```

Run the code:

```dart
void main() async {
  var midResult = _function(data);
  var finalResult = getFinalResult(midResult);

  print(finalResult);
}
```

Output Should look like this:

```dart
{Anxiety: [3, 2], Stress: [2, 0], Chronic Fatigue: [2, 1], Fatigue: [0], Involvement: [0], Slight Fatigue: [1], Relaxation: [1]}
```